# Python: How to put binary variables in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several columns that looks like this,

```
   a    b    c    d  
        Y         Y
   Y               
             Y    Y
```

I want to clean these column by assigning 0 in the blank cells and replace the "Y" with 1.

How to achieve this in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all other values are blank then you can use this simple approach:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x=='Y' else 0)
```

Comment: This works in the whole dataframe. Is there a way to apply it on certain range of columns?

Comment: @AmalNasir just select those specific columns - e.g . df[col_list] = df[col_list].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x=='Y' else 0)

Comment: Thank you so much!